# Launch music from sd card in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, sd-card, launcher

I am working a wp8 app which can read some different types file.Then launch them in a simply way.Like we can launch mp3 using ***MediaPlayerLauncher*** .But I failed.Any help will be kind to me.Thanks

Comment: How did you fail? What did you try, and what happened?

Comment: ok,I added extensions file type for my app like mp3y for mp3(which is reserved).Then i just wanted to launch the *.mp3y using MediaPlayerLauncher,but the absolute path of this *.mp3 is sadly wrong(i know it from debugging).Now  I am stopped here.Any help.thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you managed to use ExternalStorage.
 Firt of all you are not able to see this (mp3) files because they are [reserved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207065%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). What you can do is to change extensions to them and copy to InternalStorage. As you have done that you can play them well with [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement%28VS.95%29.aspx) or [BackGroundAudio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394039%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).
Also it's not possible (for now) to play directly from ExternalStorage (SD card).

Comment: First,thanks for help.I have add file extensions like mp3y for mp3,and it worked.I get the list of files(the file named *.mp3y) now.But you opinion,copy *.mp3y to internalStorage,I will try it out.

Comment: I've not tried to play Uri from a file in external storage name.mp3y, and I've not tried also to play file in InternalStorage name.mp3y - I doubt it, but please give me a sign if that worked. What I do - I copy file name.mp3y to name.mp3 in InternalStorage and it playes well.

Comment: I have finished it all.Yes,your idea is completely worked well.Here is my way to finish the code,I get the stream of the ExternalStorageFile,copy to a filestrem which is the file in the internal storage,then I launcher it as a uri ,it worked well.Thank you one more.

Comment: @user3059772 please tell me one thing - have you tested to play filestream from file with different extension eg. name.mp3y (not changing extension during copy operation to internal storage)? Also don't forget to mark answer as solution if it solved your problem :)